# How to find value in a range of following rows - SQL Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata, partitioning

I have a table with the following columns: 
account, validity_date,validity_month,amount.
For each row i want to check if the value in field "amount' exist over the rows range of the **next month**. if yes, indicator=1, else 0.

```
account   validity_date   validity_month   amount    **required_column**
-------   -------------   ---------------  -------   ----------------
123        15oct2019       201910           400         0
123        20oct2019       201910           500         1
123        15nov2019       201911           1000        0
123        20nov2019       201911           500         0
123        20nov2019       201911           2000        1
123        15dec2019       201912           400         
123        15dec2019       201912           2000
```

Can anyone help?
Thanks

Comment: What happens if 10oct and 20nov match?  Is that validly in the "next month"?  Or do you really mean "within the next 30 days"?  In either case, step 1 is to have numbers, not strings, for the dates.

Comment: Next month refers to all days for the next calendar month. if 10oct and 20nov match it is validly.

Answer (score 1):

`validity_month/100*12 + validity_month MOD 100` calculates a month number (for comparing across years, Jan to previous Dec) and the inner ROW_NUMBER reduces multiple rows with the same amount per month to a single row (kind of DISTINCT):

```
SELECT dt.*
  ,CASE -- next row is from next month
     WHEN Lead(nextMonth IGNORE NULLS)
          Over (PARTITION BY account, amount
                ORDER BY validity_date)
        = (validity_month/100*12 + validity_month MOD 100) +1
     THEN 1
     ELSE 0
   END
FROM
 (
   SELECT t.*
     ,CASE -- one row per account/month/amount
        WHEN Row_Number()
             Over (PARTITION BY account, amount, validity_month
                   ORDER BY validity_date ) = 1 
            THEN validity_month/100*12 + validity_month MOD 100
            END AS nextMonth
   FROM tab AS t
 ) AS dt
```

Edit:

The previous is for exact matching amounts, for a range match the query is probably very hard to write with OLAP-functions, but easy with a Correlated Subquery:

```
SELECT t.*
  ,CASE
     WHEN 
      ( -- check if there's a row in the next month matching the current amount +/- 10 percent
        SELECT Count(*)
        FROM tab AS t2
        WHERE t2.account_ = t.account_
        AND (t2.validity_month/100*12 + t2.validity_month MOD 100)
          = ( t.validity_month/100*12 +  t.validity_month MOD 100) +1
        AND t2.amount BETWEEN t.amount * 0.9 AND t.amount * 1.1
      ) > 0 
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END
FROM tab AS t
```

But then performance might be really bad...

Comment: thank dnoeth! And if i need not necessarily the same amount but also if the amount is closed in a range of 10 percent (meaning if in oct2019 i have row with amount of 500, and in the next month i have 520, i also want to put indicator =1). many thanks for the help!

Comment: That's a completely different logic, easy to write, but hard to execute

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the values are unique *within* a month and you have a value for each month for each account, you can simplify this to:

```
select t.*,
       (case when lead(seqnum) over (partition by account, amount order by validity_month) = seqnum + 1
             then 1 else 0
        end)
from (select t.*,
             dense_rank() over (partition by account order by validity_month) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t;
```

Note:  This puts `0` for the last month rather than `NULL`, but that can easily be adjusted.

You can do this without the subquery by using month arithmetic.  It is not clear what the data type of `validity_month` is.  If I assume a number:

```
select t.*,
       (case when lead(floor(validity_month / 100) * 12 + (validity_month mod 100)
                      ) over (partition by account, amount order by validity_month) = 
                  (validity_month / 100) * 12 + (validity_month mod 100) - 1
             then 1 else 0
        end)
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add another way to do this using Standard SQL.  This query will return `1` when the condition is met, `0` when it is not, and `null` when there isn't a next month to evaluate (as implied in your result column).

It is assumed that we're partitioning on the `account` field.  Also includes a 10% range match on the `amount` field based on the comment made.  Note that if you have an `id` field, you should include it (if two rows have the same `account`, `validity_date`, `validity_month`, `amount` there will only be one resulting row, due to `DISTINCT`).

Performance-wise, should be similar to the answer from @dnoeth.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  t1.account, 
  t1.validity_date,
  t1.validity_month, 
  t1.amount, 
  CASE 
    WHEN t2.amount IS NOT NULL THEN 1 
    WHEN MAX(t1.validity_month) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.account) > t1.validity_month THEN 0
    ELSE NULL
  END AS flag
FROM `project.dataset.table` t1
LEFT JOIN `project.dataset.table` t2 
ON 
  t2.account = t1.account AND
  DATE_DIFF(
    PARSE_DATE("%Y%m", CAST(t2.validity_month AS STRING)),
    PARSE_DATE("%Y%m", CAST(t1.validity_month AS STRING)),
    MONTH
  ) = 1 AND
  t2.amount BETWEEN t1.amount * 0.9 AND t1.amount * 1.1;
```

Comment: Standard SQL doesn't support DATE_DIFF/PARSE_DATE, this is T-SQL syntax :-) Otherwise performance (at least in Teradata) should be similar. There's just a potential issue with the join: it might return duplicate rows (e.g. two rows with 400 matching 3 rows with 390/400/410 next month returns 2*3=6 rows) and then you need to add a final DISTINCT which might remove existing duplicates...

Comment: @dnoeth thanks for pointing out the join issue -- now fixed.  Is BigQuery Standard SQL (what I used) not the same as "standard" Standard SQL?

Comment: Just because Google names it "Standard SQL" doesn't mean it's actually implementing *ISO 9075 SQL:2016* :-) Of course, most syntax is standard, but there's always some variation.